# Where is the conventional directory to put nonviewable file resources in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to ruby/rails application development but have been using java for several years.

In java there is typically a /resources directory somewhere that one places nonviewable resources.  I'm thinking of resources like templates for doing backend processing like a rules engine, or templates used when communicating with 3rd party sources that use XML in a nonstandard fashion (non SOAPy web services).

I can't seem to find any convention for where I should place these kind of resources other than inside of the .rb files themselves (which just feels wrong to me, but maybe that is the ruby way?)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the standard best practice is, I'd opt to put this stuff in the lib directory.

Comment: Thx for the answer.  It looks like this may be the way I have to go, at least for now.  I guess it just seems somehow 'wrong' to me to have to do FILE level searches for this sort of resource.